# VBNET: How to Reset ComboBox after selection is made

Tags: vb.net, combobox

How do I reset a ComboBox to default Text i set in properties. Say I have a ComboBox with default text "*Rub*y" which when SelectedIndexChanged is printed in TextBox afterwards it does'nt reset to default text "*Ruby*" but the SelectedItem. I want it to read "*Ruby*" afterwards or all the time if not possible. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Declare the helper class variable in the form class:
   `Dim _originalComboText As String`
2. On opening the form, remember the default text of the control in some helper variable. For example, add the following line into the constructor (`Sub New()`):
   `_originalComboText = ComboBox1.Text`
3. Every time after the selection is made, restore the text from it:
   `ComboBox1.Text = _originalComboText`

If you inspect the content of the `.designer.vb` file belonging to your form, you can actually see initialization of text of your control through the assignment (`=`) – so [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) does no special magic here. If you want to preserve the text, you have to save it somewhere before it gets lost.

Here is the complete minimum example:

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Dim _originalComboText As String

    Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        _originalComboText = ComboBox1.Text

    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Leave
        ComboBox1.Text = _originalComboText
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_LocationChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.LocationChanged
        ComboBox1.Text = _originalComboText
    End Sub

End Class
```

And if your two handlers do not differ, then replace them just with one – with two events in Handles clause:

```vb
    Private Sub ComboBox1_RestoreText(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
            Handles ComboBox1.Leave, ComboBox1.LocationChanged

        ComboBox1.Text = _originalComboText

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but I discovered the solution after playing around with declarations.

Comment: I am sorry but your answer doesnt work. Mine does though

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. But "Does not work" is very vague so I can't help you. Maybe you can be more specific. On my side, the code works flawlessly.

Comment: @mirolav - Now its clear. Its the most efficient way to do it. Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't say this is the best way of doing it - there are still two methods with exactly the same body. Why not have a single method which handles both events?

Comment: @JonSkeet – you are definitely right. I wasn't sure whether in reality they are same or not. But I added that into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Leave
    ComboBox1.Text = "Ruby"
End Sub
 Private Sub ComboBox1_LocationChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.LocationChanged
    ComboBox1.Text = "Ruby"
End Sub
```

Since the user will choose, say `print <<"EOF"; ---mytext---EOF` from dropdown list and this will automatically print on textbox. He or she must go to textbox or somewhere else.

I know its not coventional to answer own question but if anyone needs help. Here it is

Comment: This solution has one minor problem. You have the value `Ruby` on 2 independent places. If you want clean code, have the text stored only once – either in form Designer or on the code itself. In my answer, I shown you how to have `Ruby` only in form designer.

Comment: I havethe value `Ruby` in form designer. That I have said in my question: "How do I reset a ComboBox to default **Text** i set in **properties**. " `Ruby` is not a dropdown item but it is there to show user the dropdown can give him/her ruby syntax.

Comment: You have the string `"Ruby"` three times now. Just implement my answer to learn how to have it only once. Repeating the same literal across the code is a bad habit which should be avoided because it leads to bugs: for example you find and update only 2 of 3 occurrences of "Ruby" – and you introduce a bug. Learn to do it correctly: do not repeat yourself.